# Show all text in Terminal window (linux server)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security

Whenever performing big tasks with lots of "text", the text gets cropped or something from above. I want to be able to read ALL that has happened.

Is this possible? because I can only read x nr of lines now.

Thanks

Comment: Console? Terminal emulator?

Comment: PuTTY..........

Comment: Increase scrollback buffer (Settongs->Window) to something larger than 200 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/) or some other file pager.

```
less bigfile.txt
```

or

```
ls -l bigdir | less
```

See [`man less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less).

Note that you can also scroll up and down in PuTTY's scrollback buffer using the scrollbar on the right or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

And you can set the font size and resize the PuTTY window to fit more text on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could also port the job's output to a file i.e. cat /etc/passwd > somefile and then open it with your favorite text editor when its finished. Nano (nano -w somefile) is my favorite as it wraps (with -w) and is quite functional. May not be what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other normal solutions here (less/more/pg), you can use the "script" command to save all the output from an interactive session for later use.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use tee for big output.  Use "big_output_cmd | tee log.txt" which will still show the output on the terminal and also dump the output to the file log.txt.

The script command will save all output from that shell session to a log file ISO just one command at a time.  Just start it with "script log.txt" and you get a shell that has all stdout/stderr getting dup'd to log.txt.